# Send Email Without Showing Compose UI In iOS 7

Tags: email, smtp, ios7.1

I have an in-house app that is used by employees.  I need functionality included in the app so that an email can be sent to a group email address in an emergency.  For this I do not want to have to show the UI and then have to require the user to press send to actually send the email.  I am trying to send a pre-written email that sends when a PIN is entered correctly.

I have seen and tried to implement SKPSMTPMessage but this does not seem to work in iOS 7.

If I send the email to an smtp service via a web service I can make this work but if there's an easier way within objective c then I would like to use that way.

Is it possible to send an email in the background in iOS 7+ in the above scenario?

Comment: SMTP is rather simple. If your app can connect to the internet, TCP port 25, sending an email message is really straight forward. - Probably, someone has already done it and provided utility functions for it. - Found one [here](http://libmailcore.com/) for example.